# Can someone explain what is happening here.Why I don't get the answer of y as 6

Tags: c, function, pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f1(int *x, int y) {
    y++;
    (*x)++;
    return *x + y;
}

int main() {
    int x = 10, y = 5;
    int z = f1(&x, y);
    printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d\n", x, y, z);
}
```

I get the answer as `x=11 y=5 z=17`.
Can someone explain this?

Comment: Did you run this in a debugger and stepped through? What did you see?

Comment: Your function takes a *copy* of `y` (it's passed  by value) and doesn't make any changes to the original variable.

Comment: The `y` in `main()` and the `y` in `f1()` are different variables. BTW: the `x` in `f1()` is a **pointer** to the `x` in `main()` (they are also different variables).

Comment: The best way to see what a program is doing is to run it line by line in a [debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/12149471), while monitoring the values of all variables.

Answer (score 1):

Check the comments.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int f1(int *x,int y)
{
    y++;  // incrementing y, which was 5, to 6.
    (*x)++;  // incrementing the value-at-address-x, which was 10, to 11
    return *x+y;  // add value-at-address-x, 11, and value of y, 6 == 17, return that.
}

int main(void)          //correct signature of main in hosted environment
{
    int x=10,y=5;
    int z=f1(&x,y);
       //any changes made to the value stored at address x will reflect here, 
       // any changes made to the value of y will be local to the function call.

    printf("x=%d y=%d z=%d\n",x,y,z);
       // updated x, unchanged y, and returned z.

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The formal arguments `x` and `y` in `f1` are *different objects in memory* from the variables `x` and `y` in `main`.

When you call `z=f1(&x, y);`, the *expressions* `&x` and `y` are fully evaluated and the results of those expressions are *copied* to the formal parameters `x` and `y` (this is what we mean when we say C passes function arguments *by value*).

So the formal parameter `x` stores the *address* of the variable `x` and the formal parameter `y` stores the value `5`.

Since the formal parameter `y` is a different object in memory from the variable `y`, changing its value has no effect on the `y` in `main`.

The *expression* `*x` is `f1` acts as kinda-sorta an alias for the variable `x`, so changing the value of `*x` in `f1` *does* change the value of `x` in `main`.